# Is it possible to find user current location in offline by using mapbox SDK in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

i am working on offline map. i am using mapbox sdk.
 But i am not able to track user current location.
 I wrote **`code like below :`**

```
  (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"control-room-0.2.0" ofType:@"mbtiles"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];
    mapView.zoom = 2;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];


    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:RMUserTrackingModeFollow animated:true];
    mapView.draggingEnabled = YES;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Thanks in advance. please help me on this

Comment: hi can any one find answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it, but you have to turn on your wifi and 3g. But if showsUserLocation doesn't work for you you can do it using CLLocationManager. Hope my code can help you.

```
- (IBAction)findMe:(id)sender {
    if (!_trackingActive) {
        NSLog(@"Tracking mode activated");
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        _startLocation = nil;
        _trackingActive = true;
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

        if ([UIView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)])
            self.mapView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.200 green:1.000 blue:0.200 alpha:1];

        self.mapView.userLocation.title = @"Hola";
        self.mapView.userLocation.badgeIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info"];
        self.mapView.userLocation.annotationIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info"];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Tracking mode deactivated");
        [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        _trackingActive = false;
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                 newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _latitude.text = currentLatitude;

    NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                  newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _longitude.text = currentLongitude;

    NSString *currentHorizontalAccuracy =
    [[NSString alloc]
     initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
     newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
    _horizontalAccuracy.text = currentHorizontalAccuracy;

    NSString *currentAltitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                 newLocation.altitude];
    _altitude.text = currentAltitude;

    NSString *currentVerticalAccuracy =
    [[NSString alloc]
     initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
     newLocation.verticalAccuracy];
    _verticalAccuracy.text = currentVerticalAccuracy;

    if (_startLocation == nil)
        _startLocation = newLocation;

    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation
                                          distanceFromLocation:_startLocation];

    NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%f",
                            distanceBetween];
    _distance.text = tripString;
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLatitude.doubleValue, currentLongitude.doubleValue);
}
```